# Stop switching windows when other app is loading

Tags: macos, window-manager

Imagine that you open an app that takes several seconds to load like Photoshop and you don't want to just sit there so you move to your browser to check whatever. Now, as you interact with browser or other app OS X will move screen or switch active window to app several times during the start.

I understand that it is letting me know that app is turning on but I would like system to stop switching at any moment it likes while I am doing something else. Otherwise I have to just keep sitting around waiting until my initial app loads.

Is there way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OS X already does this.** If you open an app, then switch app before the window loads, the window of the second app will open behind the app you are currently working in.

Photoshop does not create standard OS X windows, instead using its own windowing system. This means that Photoshop windows and therefore the app itself does not abide by OS X windowing standards.